# find with ls but with full pathes

Tags: shell, find, ls

Example :

```
find /sdcard/ \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.sh' \) -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r      552 2016-01-11 02:31 scr.sh
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r       12 2017-06-20 09:44 2.gif
```

will print scr.sh and 2.gif with no full pathes?
How print this with full pathes like

```
-rw-rw---- root sdcard_r 552 2016-01-11 02:31 /sdcard/scr.sh
```

or something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute path with ls?](https://serverfault.com/questions/242227/absolute-path-with-ls)

Comment: not exactly duplicate , i think

Comment: Works fine for me: `find /boot/ -name "*default" -exec ls -l {} \;` gives
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7241840 Jul 22 05:01 /boot/vmlinuz-4.11.8-2-default`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have should work - for example:

**Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)**

```
$ find /var/www/html -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Nov 29  2016 /var/www/html/index.html
```

**Linux (CentOS 7)**

```
$ find ~/ -iname '*.txt' -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-rw-r-- 1 craig craig 0 Jul 18 08:33 /home/craig/1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 craig craig 0 Jul 18 08:33 /home/craig/2.txt
```

**Mac (10.11.6)**

```
$ find ~/Desktop \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.localized' \) -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-r--r--  1 craig  staff  0 13 May  2016 /Users/craig/Desktop/.localized
-rw-r--r--  1 craig  staff  0 18 Jul 09:29 /Users/craig/Desktop/file.txt
```

Comment: My fall, i'm try before in Android shell. With toolbox ls - print no pathes, with busybox ls - all fine. Hmm. Thanks.

Comment: Another problem. If find print folder - ls print list in folder. How avoid this without -type f ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `-ls` subcommand:

```
find /sdcard/ \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.sh' \) -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the directory where you want to search from, subbing in `pwd` will make find print full paths. E.g:

```
cd /sdcard/
find $(pwd) \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.sh' \)
```